# Nginx - Default server catches all - why?

Tags: nginx, server, default

I have got 2 different URLs that are correctly redirected by Proxy_Pass.

However as soon as I add the default_server (first server below), my 2 URLs are not redirected anymore. They fall into the catch all.

Why is that? I don't understand what is wrong in the default configuration. Thanks for your help!

```
# default server for this IP
server{
       listen xx.xx.xx.xx:8443 default_server;
       server_name _;
       return 404;
}

server{
        listen xx.xx.xx.xx:8443;
        server_name *.staging1.yyyy.com staging1.yyyy.com;

        ssl on;
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yyyy.com/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yyyy.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6981;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}


server{
        listen xx.xx.xx.xx:8443;
        server_name *.staging2.yyyy.com .staging2.yyyy.com 

        ssl on;
            ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/yyyy.com/fullchain.pem;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/yyyy.com/privkey.pem;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6982;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
}
```

Comment: Did you tried changing the order ? move default to the last.

Comment: Maybe, but is not more logical/usual to put the default as first?
I'll try that anyway to see what it does.

Comment: I did put the default at the end. But it still caught everything.

Comment: You have inconsistent `ssl` settings and `ssl on` is deprecated. Try: `listen xx.xx.xx.xx:8443 ssl default_server;` and `listen xx.xx.xx.xx:8443 ssl;`, and you will need to provide a certificate in the default block otherwise Nginx will not restart. Also, does this server have more than one IP address. You could simplify the configuration by using `listen 8443 ssl default_server;` and `listen 8443 ssl;` instead.

Comment: Thanks! indeed, I did not notice there was a difference on the ssl side. That's probably the issue. I'll look into this.
Indeed I have several IPs. That's why I use them to filter accordingly.